# Who was the Supporter of the Seleção in Eden of the East?

Tags: eden-of-the-east

It seems like this was never really addressed. This piqued my curiosity primarily because the supporter was stated by Mr. Outside to be one of the Seleção, and it seemed odd that one of the Seleção would willingly facilitate the game by enforcing its rules. Furthermore, the Supporter would have nothing to fear from breaking the rules of the game, so it would seem logical for him/her to pocket the money and do with it as he/she pleases. So that would seem to indicate that the Supporter is someone in league with Mr. Outside.

But who was the Supporter? All the evidence seems to indicate that it was Number XII, but can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, every player in the game is the supporter, and every player is not.  Because the concept that a player may be officially designated the supporter would create a situation of impunity (who watches the watcher?), and players are told that even the supporter may not know that is there role, it makes much more sense that the players all can fulfill this purpose.

There is a point at which one player will look at the actions of another and feel they are self-serving, and decide they need to put an end to them.  They may try to confront the other party, use their funds to hinder or redirect them, or destroy their efforts.  But in the end, if they come to believe they have a moral out in the role of the supporter, and virtually unlimited funds to get them out of the legal trouble, the societal justice impulse could kick in, and they may kill the player.

There is also a possibility, based on the nature of Juiz, that Juiz may also help fulfill this role.  There may be certain conditions or thresholds that will trigger actions by the long arm of the concierge to take actions against misguided players.  This is not evidenced (that I can remember), but it is also possible that Juiz may indirectly responsible for a player acting in the role of the supporter, by ensuring that actions that would trigger them to retaliate will come to their attention.

Alternatively, self-serving players may be fed information that will cause them to act offensively to another, instigating retaliation from the offended by the information they, in turn, are delivered.

Also, keep in mind that a player overtly acting as the supporter would be seen as a threat to every other player, and would almost certainly become a target themselves, since transactional data becomes public upon use.

All theoretical, but there may be something there.  Pleasure to serve.  Nobelesse oblige.

Comment: Nice theory. Paranoia is the best the threat to keep the players in check.

Comment: Sadly I don't think we'll ever have an official answer, but this theory is so well-thought out I have to accept it! I never even considered the possibility of Seleçao being coerced by Juiz into taking others out, but it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

The supporter is never revealed because there might not have even been one. When No.9 was given a phone he is told by Mr. Outside that "the supporter might not even know he is the supporter".

Answer (score 0):

It's not confirmed who the Supporter is, it's left open to interpretation. It's possible that it's Seleção No. 8, since we don't know much about him (or No. 7) but at least No. 8 seems to be familiar with Mr. Outside. It's possible that Mr. Outside is the Supporter, being the one who judges is the money was used correctly or not.

But seeing as how it was revealed that Hajime Hiura actually wasn't killed by the Supporter in the *The King of Eden movie* and that the "proper" use of the money can seem to be anything (including covering up murder or firing missiles at Japan), it's possible that there *is no Supporter* and it was just something Mr. Outside made up in order to keep all the Seleção in check and suspicious enough of each other so there would be no collusion.

Answer (score 0):

The supporter could be 7 or 8 as they are never seen doing anything or Mr. Outside AKA no. 12 (AKA Ato Saizo) could be the supporter. Most likely he just would wipe the memory of the person. At the end of the game he does wipe all the other alive player memories but 9 keeps his possibly due to him already having wiped it twice. Then he asks the next person he picks up the question he uses to select them. Then 9 hits him with a slipper (lol)

Answer (score 0):

It is Juiz. No. IV, in episode 3 was sabotaged by juiz making sure the text message went to his wife instead of his mistress.